# Setting a reference's type in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently using something like

```
class User{

    /* @var Contacts*/
    public $contacts = array();
}

$userObj = new User();
$userObj->contacts[] = new Contact(...);
$userObj->contacts[] = new Contact(...);
```

Tough we can document the type of variable using phpDocumentor, is it also possible to restrict other types of objects to be assigned to the contacts array

```
$userObj->contacts[] = 2.3 //should be considered as invalid
```

Comment: It's just an array... so no. But you could do something with magic methods and setters/getters, perhaps, to finagle around it.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: that's what getters and setters are for. don't use public access when you need to control the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not how it works in php

Here is what you can do instead

```
class User{

    /* @var Contacts*/
    private $contacts = array();

    public function setContacts(Contact $contact){
        $this->contacts[] = $contacts;
    }
}
```

No you can use it like so

```
$userObj = new User();
$userObj->setContacts(new Contact(...));
```

And the following will cause an error

```
$userObj->setContacts(2.3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `$contacts` as private and use getter and setter methods.

```
Class User{

  private $contacts = array();

  function addContact($contact) {
    if (is_object($contact) && get_class($contact) == "Contact") {
      $this->contacts[] = $contact;
    } else {
      return false;
      // or throw new Exception('Invalid Parameter');  
    }
  }

  function getContacts() {
    return $this->contacts;
  }
}
```